# Can't find solution to "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create some tables with foreign keys and I get this error.

- I'm not creating the foreign key before creating the referenced
  table.
- I've also tried using ALTER TABLE statements to add the
  foreign key constraints.
- Both fields have the same data type.
- It's not an int so it's not about the unsigned int issue
- I've read about indexing the foreign key, but I don't understand how to do it and I'm not a 100% sure why I should it.

These are my CREATE TABLEs:

```
    CREATE TABLE snmptt_listpolls ( 
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      ip varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no_ip_found', 
      polling_time int(10) NOT NULL, 
      communitydata varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
      snmp_oid varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL, 
      lastcheck datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE snmptt_nodes (  
      ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
      ip varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no_ip_found',   
      PRIMARY KEY (ID),
      UNIQUE KEY ip(ip),
      FOREIGN KEY (ip) REFERENCES snmptt_listpolls(ip)) ;
```

> ### ------------------------ LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> 151015 12:42:24 Error in foreign key constraint of table noname_jc_sandbox/snmptt_nodes: FOREIGN KEY (ip)
>   REFERENCES snmptt_listpolls(ip)): Cannot find an index in the
>   referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first
>   columns, or column types in the table and the referenced table do not
>   match for constraint. Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and
>   SET changed in tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns
>   in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it:

> ...Cannot find an index in the referenced table...

Do this before creating snmptt_nodes table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_snmptt_listpolls_ip ON snmptt_listpolls(ip);
```

Answer (score 3):

Although irrelevant to OP I would still like to point out that this error is caused due another arcane reason.

The reason is CHARSET. If you created referenced table using CHARSET=latin1 (I didnt provide a charset when I created the table maybe it was default) and try to create referencing table using some other CHARSET,say utf8, then you'll get this error too.

Bottomline: Make sure CHARSET of referencing and referenced tables are same.